# php how to put a Session link to array_filter(glob)

Tags: php, ajax

I would like to paste $link to folder path, . What else the echo show that path is correct.

```
$link = 'files' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_SESSION['user']['username'];
$folder = array_filter(glob('files/$_SESSION['user']['username']/*'), 'is_dir');
```

Only is working if it is like that:

```
$folder = array_filter(glob('files/user1/*'), 'is_dir');
```

I hope you understand what i mean, i always have problem to explain errors in whole my life. Regards

Comment: Is this about your syntax error / not knowing how to interpolate or concat strings?

Comment: Ohh sorry, i'm still learning, I was trying but i skipped some '', but thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your strings/quotation marks are being used improperly. You have to concatenate the strings like you did in the first line. Here's how it should look:

```
$folder = array_filter(glob('files/' . $_SESSION['user']['username'] . '/*'), 'is_dir');
```

Comment: Thanks, It's working, I was doing something like this, but I skipped some '' cause of my small skills(still learning). Really thank to you